# Reading specific positions of a file and writing it in a new file in python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a file of string of bytes that looks something as below:

00101000000000011000000000000011001.......

I want to read every 8th bits of the binary file and write it in a new file. How do I do it in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
endianness = 'big'

with open('from.txt', 'rb') as r:
    with open('to.txt', 'wb') as w:
        while True:
            chars = r.read(8)
            if len(chars) == 8:
                string = ''.join([str(byte % 2) for byte in chars])
                if endianness == 'little':
                    string = string[::-1]
                byte = int(string, 2).to_bytes(1, endianness)
                w.write(byte)
            else:
                break
```